# Seaching .csv for unwanted string and delete

Tags: python, regex, csv

I am running a test on a short`.csv`:
This is how my "raw" `.csv` looks like:

```
> print test.csv
> onü, toé, 112 #first line in .csv
> four, FIVE, seven #second line in .csv
```

I want to read it out and do some string formatting.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
allowed = re.compile("[^0-9a-zA-Z\s,.:]")
myJoin = ""
with open("test.csv") as f:
    for i in f:
        splitted = i.split(",")
        myString = ",".join(splitted)
        myList = list(myString)
        for j in allowed.finditer(myString):
            x = int(j.start())
            del myList[x]
```

When I print out `x` I get this output:

```
> x 
> 2
> 3
> 8
> 9
```

I thought I allwed white spaces, commas in my `allowed`?!
I cannot get my head around why it marks these as "not supposed to be in there". Furthermore I cannot get straight how to write that back into a `.csv` which looks like this.

My new, "clean" `.csv`:

```
> print test.csv
> on, to, 112 #first line in .csv
> four, FIVE, seven #second line in .csv
```

Comment: Use `re.sub( r'[^0-9a-zA-Z\s,.:]', '', i )`

Comment: @hjpotter92 where and how and why?

Comment: When you create a pattern with: `[^`, you are negating the characters inside the set.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Sure. Defensive Programming. I want everything which is **NOT** in that set of characters/signs to be deleted!

Comment: To confirm, you want to throw away the filename and keep the extension?

Comment: @MartinEvans I edited my Question. I hope its clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Python's `csv` module to help with this. The following should give you the desired results:

```
import csv
import re

with open('input.csv', 'r') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, skipinitialspace=True)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    keep = re.compile(r'[^0-9a-zA-Z\s,.:]')

    for cols in csv_input:
        cols = [keep.sub('', col) for col in cols]
        csv_output.writerow(cols)
```

Giving you an `output.csv` as follows:

```
on,to,112
four,FIVE,seven
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing different from Martin Evans answer except that it uses a replacement for each items:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
import re
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'rb') as source, open('result.csv', 'wb') as destination:
    allowed = re.compile(r'[^0-9a-z,.:\s]+', re.I)
    csv.register_dialect('mydial', delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, skipinitialspace=True)
    testreader = csv.reader(source, 'mydial')
    reswriter = csv.writer(destination, 'mydial')
    for row in testreader:
        reswriter.writerow([allowed.sub('', x) for x in row])
```

Note that leading spaces will disappear in the result, but it isn't a bad thing.

Comment: I accetp Martin Evans answer because I understad it better. thanks!